# Tomcat URL could not be accessed by another PC

Tags: java, tomcat

I am using openstack to launch a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo) and install apache tomcat 9.0.17 in it, deploy a web app, but I cannot access to this tomcat url for example http://10.157.166.142:8080 via my another windows pc which is in the same internal network. but I can use it in the linux.

And I also add following to catalina.sh to bind ipv4 only and before making this change, It binds to ipv6 only, but still it is not accessed by other pc

```
JAVA_OPTS=" $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true "
```

curl -v http://localhost:8080 is working fine.

ip: 192.168.0.14
elastic ip : 10.157.166.142

```
[root@bigdata]# netstat -tupln | grep :8080
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               
LISTEN      21373/java

[root@bigdata bin]# service iptables status
  Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status iptables.service
  ● iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; disabled; 
  vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

with the tcpdump and I try to access from my windows pc and get the following logs:

```
[root@bigdata docker.service.d]# tcpdump -i eth0 port 8080
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
10:32:07.738897 IP 10.141.174.148.54346 > bigdata.novalocal.webcache: Flags [S], seq 2866917131, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
10:32:07.741243 IP 10.141.174.148.54347 > bigdata.novalocal.webcache: Flags [S], seq 3985678636, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
10:32:07.990685 IP 10.141.174.148.54350 > bigdata.novalocal.webcache: Flags [S], seq 577076481, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
10:32:10.739649 IP 10.141.174.148.54346 > bigdata.novalocal.webcache: Flags [S], seq 2866917131, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
10:32:10.741583 IP 10.141.174.148.54347 > bigdata.novalocal.webcache: Flags [S], seq 3985678636, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
10:32:10.990666 IP 10.141.174.148.54350 > bigdata.novalocal.webcache: Flags [S], seq 577076481, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
10:32:16.738767 IP 10.141.174.148.54346 > bigdata.novalocal.webcache: Flags [S], seq 2866917131, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
10:32:16.741559 IP 10.141.174.148.54347 > bigdata.novalocal.webcache: Flags [S], seq 3985678636, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
10:32:16.990632 IP 10.141.174.148.54350 > bigdata.novalocal.webcache: Flags [S], seq 577076481, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
```

```
[root@bigdata docker.service.d]# lsof -i :8080 | grep LISTEN
java    21373 root   54u  IPv4 90812729      0t0  TCP *:webcache (LISTEN)
```

Comment: The `curl` you mentioned is using `localhost`. Are you able to `ping` the IP from your windows machine? If not check whether there is any firewall which is running which is blocking the IP.

Comment: I can ping the linux from window pc, It is working.

Comment: Once I installed elasticsearch 6.6.2 and also has this problem, I cannot access to the url via another pc, but setting following make it work 
    network.host: 0.0.0.0

    http.port: 9200

Answer (score 0):

Check the firewall rules once. Port `8080` might not be opened by default. 
On the machine where the application is deployed, you will have to add new rule to iptables to open the port.

1. Edit iptables `vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables`
2. Append new rule to open port 8080 as follow
   `-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT`
3. Save the file and exit with `esc+:+w+q` or check [this link](http://itproguru.com/expert/2016/11/how-to-exit-quit-vi-editor-without-saving-changes-step-by-step/) to see how to exit `vi` editor after saving changes
4. Reload iptables with `/etc/init.d/iptables restart`

Comment: Hello, the firewall is not up.

Comment: If you are accessing from elastic ip, you will have to open port 8080 on the security group because requesting is being routed from the internet.

Comment: curl -v http://192.168.0.14:8080 cannot work. but telnet 192.168.0.14 8080 can work on linux.

Comment: I have opened the port in security group.

Comment: my window 10 ip in the company: 10.141.174.148 and I think the openstack may be in the private cloud as I can only access to it after connecting a vpn of the company.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Yogesh Badke. and add the following rule works.

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```